Error: Insufficient params provided for localized pathname (getPathname()). Since I added "next-intl/routing"
Since I added the config file and replace :
Navigation File
import { createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation, Pathnames } from 'next-intl/navigation';

By :
Config File
import {Pathnames, LocalePrefix} from 'next-intl/routing';} 

Navigation File
import { createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation } from "next-intl/navigation";
import { locales, pathnames, localePrefix } from "./config";

I get this error everytime I use the function getPathname(). For example:
Error: Insufficient params provided for localized pathname.
Template: /blog/[categorySlug]
Params: undefined

The weird thing is since I added 'next-intl/routing', typescript is telling me that I need to use "query" instead of "params" :
  const path = getPathname({
    locale: locale,
    href: {
      pathname: "/blog/[categorySlug]",
      query: { categorySlug: 'news' },
    },
  });

But query doesn't seems to work.
When I look on the doc or working example, it looks like next-intl is using params and not query but that doesn't match the type of getPathname() for me…
Here is what typescript telling me:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'params' does not exist in type '{ pathname: string; } & { query?: Record<string, SearchParamValue> | undefined; }'.

Wondering if it's a bug from next-intl. I am really lost here… Thank you for your help!

I had the same problem. My current workaround is to use any:
(router as any).push(
  {
    pathname,
    params
  },
  { locale: locale }
);

I was on v3.15.5 and updated to the latest(v3.17.2) but the types haven't been updated yet.

Thank you for your answer! I used any on getPathname() and it's working fine! Do you think it's a bug from Next Intl? If so I will create a ticket.

Not sure if its a bug(ie a broken system) since it works with the workaround, but im sure people who use typescript may encounter the issue so it might be good to let them know. Most probably its just a matter of updating the typings in next-intl.

While waiting for a fix, here is what worked for me (by following the answer of Arunmenon) :
  const path = getPathname({
    locale: locale,
    href: {
      pathname: pathname,
      params: query,
    },
  } as any);

